# Node.js : newly created header (res.header) not appearing in Chrome

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, token, response-headers

I'm fairly new to JavaScript, Express & NodeJS. I'm having trouble where I'm trying to create a new header that contain a token when user login (*as shown below  in login POST router*)

```
// Login POST Router
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {

    // 1. Validatation
    const {error} = loginValidation(req.body)
    // if has error don't save
    if(error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message)

    // 2. Check the existance of user/email in db
    const userEmail = await User.findOne({email: req.body.email})
    // if 'same/exist', then throw 'message/error'
    if(!userEmail) return res.status(400).send(`Email doesn't exist!`)

    // 3. Chack password (is correct)
    const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, userEmail.password)
    if(!validPassword) return res.status(400).send(`Invalid password!`)

    // 4. Create & assign token to user
    const token = jwt.sign({_id: userEmail._id}, process.env.TOKEN_LOGINUSER)
    // add 'token' to header - just for identifier (can be any name)
    res.header('auth-token', token).json({ message: 'Logged In'})
})
```

Where then the login page that make the fetch request (**login.js** coded in Vanilla JavaScript) will do a **redirect** to a home page (*as shown below in login.js - Login page*)

```
if(loginRespond === 'Logged In') {

    let homeURL = '/index.html'
    window.location.replace(homeURL)
 }
```

then back in NodeJS, i have a router for **home or '/'** that use a function to verify the token first (*as shown below*)

```
router.get('/', verify, async (req, res) => {

    const data = await All.findById({ _id: req.user._id})
    res.json(data.data)
})
```

and have a JSON Web token **verify function** (*as shown below*)

```
// Middleware function
function verify(req, res, next) {

    // get token from header
    const token = req.header('auth-token')
    // if have, then allow. If don't have, then don't allow
    if(!token) return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Accessed denied!' })

    try {

        // verify the exist token
        const varified = jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_4LOGINUSER)
        req.user = varified
        next()
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Invalid token!' })
    }
}
```

And these are my **Middlewares**

```
// B. Global Middleware
// 1. Handle cors
app.use(cors())
// 2. Handle JSON body-parser
app.use(express.json())
```

Everything works fine when testing it with **Postman**. But unfortunately, not with the live site. Since **auth-token** was never created and can't be found in **Response Header** of the homepage in Chrome (*as shown below*)

[image: index.html or Homepage]

Since I'm new to express & nodejs, I don't actually know how to tackle this prob. I've try searching it through google. But can't find the right sentence or keyword to search for.

Hope you guys can point me where to look at and what should I read or learn before attempting to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to expose your custom header by adding an `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header.

```
res
    .header('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', 'auth-token')
    .header('auth-token', token)
    .json({ message: 'Logged In'})
```

This is required for it to work in the browser but not for Postman.

The Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header indicates which headers can be exposed as part of the response by listing their names.

As an alternative, you can provide a custom options parameter to your cors middleware: `app.use(cors({ exposedHeaders: 'auth-token' }))`. It expects a comma-delimited string (ex: ‘Content-Range,X-Content-Range’) or an array (ex: ['Content-Range', 'X-Content-Range']).

Follows [documentation on this from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

By default, only the 7 CORS-safelisted response headers are exposed:

- Cache-Control
- Content-Language
- Content-Length
- Content-Type
- Expires
- Last-Modified
- Pragma

If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to list them using the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.

Comment: Sorry if this question might sound ignorant, the **Middlewares** that I have created `app.use(cor())` does this not already cover the custom header - `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`?

Comment: The cors middleware will only cover the 7 CORS-safelisted headers described in my answer. Any other response header will require the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header.

Comment: You can also provide a custom options parameter to your cors middleware: `app.use(cors({ exposedHeaders: 'auth-token' }))`. It expects a comma-delimited string (ex: ‘Content-Range,X-Content-Range’) or an array (ex: ['Content-Range', 'X-Content-Range']).

Comment: Both ways are not working. The `auth-token` is still not able to register in the header. Do I need to specify something on the receiving end of the fetch in `login.js`before I redirect to `home/index.html` page?

Comment: The `auth-token` will not be available in `index.html` and there is no way to pass it as a "response parameter", since you are using a redirect. You can pass it as a get parameter `index.html?auth-token=TOKEN` in the redirect, then access it as `(new URL(window.location.href)).searchParams.get("auth-token")`. However, it would be bad practice, since you would be sending the user object as a get parameter.

Comment: Or is it because my login post `router` is an async function?

Comment: Oh I see! Now I understand. The one that get the `auth-token` registered to the header of the page is the page that execute the fetch. All along the `auth-token` was on my login page. Since I redirect my page to the homepage once all credentials match with what's in the database. Basically the 'auth-token' need to be re-declare again somehow? or like you mentioned above passing it through `get parameter`. But as you said, it's not ideal. Anyway, thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. I was looking at the Response Header in my Homepage. That's why I found nothing. Thanks again!

Comment: Try saving the token in localStorage before the redirect with `localStorage.setItem('auth-token', token)` and then get it back on the other page with `localStorage.getItem('auth-token')`, assuming both pages are on the same domain.

Comment: Yeah it works! So, this mean I can't just basically depends on on JWT/token-based approach. I do need to incorporate session also. Thanks for the help!