# How do you get "x-" headers in Next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-headers, next.js

I am following an example from Sara Vieira's 
[Opinionated Guide to React](https://opinionatedreact.com/).  In the example, she is doing something like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
  const ip = req.headers['x-real-ip']
  console.log(req.headers)
  const { data } = await axios(`http://ip-api.com/json/${ip}`)

  return {
    props: {
      location: data,
    },
  }
}
```

My console log of the headers is:

```
{
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
  Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7,it;q=0.6'
```

}

None of the `x-` headers are coming through.  I am thinking it is because I am running `dev`

According to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7377 the `x-` headers can only be accessed in `_app.js` or `_document.js` due to SSR.

Can you help!

Comment: can you try to use curl -i -H "x-forward-for: 1.1.1.1" http://localhost:3000 locally to see if you can see the x- header?

Comment: Possibly you need to expose the header to the client by adding it to 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers'? See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60652494

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { req } = context;
  
  // Access custom "x-" headers using the req object
  const customHeader = req.headers['x-custom-header'];
  
  // Now, you can use the customHeader value in your logic
  // ...

  return {
    props: {
      // Your data to pass to the component
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.